# Can we call event from public static method in the same class?

Tags: c#, events

Trying to understand event concepts..

Is it possible to call public event from the static function in the same class in my code below? it works if I use instance of program class.

I am leaving the "**This**" keyword as it is there for your review as I don't know what **object** for **sender** to put there. 
I already checked this [How to call a public event from a static function in the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341368/how-to-call-a-public-event-from-a-static-function-in-the-same-class) but didn't get the concept.

Let me know if it is possible what I am trying to do and how?

```
using System;

namespace CSharp_ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            loggingInProgramClass = OnLoggingEvent;
            ShowLogging();
        }

        public static event DMethod_ShowCategory_ShowLogging_Event loggingInProgramClass;
        public static void ShowLogging()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Show Logging method executed...");
            loggingInProgramClass(**this**, new EventArgs());
        }

        private static void OnLoggingEvent(**object sender**,EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event triggered...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply pass `null`.

Comment: The sender and EventArgs pattern is not mandatory. You can have events without arguments at all - if you can change the definition of DMethod_ShowCategory_ShowLogging_Event.And by the way, this thing is a delegate, don't call it an event.  loggingInProgramClass is your event.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't have a `sender` for the `EventHandler` delegate. The fast solution would be to just pass `null` as `sender` or you could use something like `Action<EventArgs>` as delegate and don't require a sender.

Comment: Or `typeof(Program)` as sender. I've seen that before.